# Multer - multiple file upload with different path and filter depending on fieldname

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have a form which POSTs FormData to an express endpoint. I'm using multer. This request can either have or not, this two fields: `screenshot` and `staticFile`.

`screenshot` should be a JPG file, less than 2mb size, and go into `assets/screenshots`. `staticFile` should be PDF file, less than 15mb size and go into `assets/pdfs`.

Right now, I have this:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'assets/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname +
        '-' +
        Date.now() +
        '.' +
        file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1]
    );
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.jpeg' && ext !== '.pdf') {
      return callback(new Error('Only images are allowed'));
    }
    callback(null, true);
  },
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 15
  }
}).any();

upload(req, res, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.end('Error');
  } else {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);

    //upload the files paths and other data to a database

    res.end('All done');
  }
});
```

As you can see, this puts both files in the `assets/` folder and I can't filter filetype or size separately.

Answer (score 1):

With the `destination` option for `multer.diskStorage()` you can specify custom destination by passing a function.

Similarly, with the `fileFilter` option for `multer()` you can allow/disallow certain files (as you have done with the extensions, it's also possible for file size) also by passing a function.

In both options, you will have access to `req` and `file`, where `file` should have the necessary properties `fieldname` and `size` according to the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information)

So you can check `file.fieldname` and set the destination path accordingly

```js
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    var destinationPath = 'assets/'
    if (file.fieldname === 'screenshot') {
      destinationPath += 'screenshot/'
    } else if (file.fieldname === 'staticFile') {
      destinationPath += 'pdfs/'
    }
    cb(null, destinationPath);
  }
```

Likewise, with fileFilter

```js
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (file.fieldname === 'screenshot') {
      if (!['.jpg', '.jpeg'].includes(ext)) {
        return callback(new Error('Only images are allowed'));
      }
      if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 2) {
        return callback(new Error('File size exceeds 2 MB'));
      }
    }
    if (file.fieldname === 'staticFile') {
      if (!['.pdf'].includes(ext)) {
        return callback(new Error('Only pdfs are allowed'));
      }
      if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 15) {
        return callback(new Error('File size exceeds 15 MB'));
      }
    }
    callback(null, true);
  },
```